# Associates in the Ring of Polynomials mod n

Tags: ring-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}[x]$. If $a$ and $b$ generate the same ideal, must they be associates? If $n$ is prime, then it is easy to see that the answer is "yes". But what if $n$ is not prime?

Comment: I did not see Robin's question. Strange coincidence!!

Comment: By "associates" I mean that there us a unit $u$ such that $au=b".

Comment: Look at the answers to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/if-r-is-a-commutative-ring-with-identity-and-a-b-are-its-elements-that-are-divi and the reference given by Robin Chapman and Bill Dubuque. That may answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at 
[the paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-34/issue-3/When-are-Associates-Unit-Multiples/10.1216/rmjm/1181069828.full) referenced by Robin Chapman and Bill Dubuque in response to [the recent closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/are-associates-unit-multiples-in-a-commutative-ring-with-1), it seems to me that the answer is "yes", though it may very well fall into mosquito-nuking territory. I hope what follows is not in error!

A commutative ring with identity $R$ is called *présimplifiable* if and only if $xy=x$ implies $x=0$ or $y\in U(R)$ ($y$ is a unit).

If $R$ is présimplifiable, then $(a)=(b)$ implies $a$ and $b$ are associates: we know that $a=bx$ for some $x$, and $b=ay$ for some $y$, so $a=bx=a(xy)$. Since $R$ is présimplifiable, either $a=0$ or $xy$ is a unit. If $a=0$, then $(a)=(0)=(b)$, so $b=0$, hence $b=a1$. If $xy$ is a unit, then $y$ is a unit, so $b=ay$ is an associate of $y$.

The paper cited above cites another paper for the following result:

**Theorem.** $R[X]$ is présimplifiable if and only if $R$ is présimplifiable and $(0)$ is a primary ideal of $R$.

Getting back to your question. First, consider the case in which $n$ is a prime power, $n=p^n$. Note that $R=\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ is présimplifiable: if $ab\equiv a \pmod{p^n}$, then $p^n|a(b-1)$. If $p^n|a$, then $\overline{a}=0$ (where $\overline{a}$ is the image of $a$ in $R$). If $p^n$ does not divide $a$, then $b-1$ must be a multiple of $p$. But if $b-1$ is a multiple. of $p$, then $b$ is relatively prime to $p$, hence $\overline{b}$ is a unit in $R$. Thus, if $\overline{a}\overline{b}=\overline{a}$ in $R$, then either $\overline{a}=0$ or $\overline{b}$ is a unit. Also, $(0)$ is a primary ideal of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$. If $\overline{a}\overline{b}\in(0)$ and $\overline{a}\notin (0)$, then $p|b$, hence some power of $b$ is a multiple of $p^n$, so there exists $j\gt 0$ with $\overline{b}^j\in(0)$. By the theorem quoted above, it follows that $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is présimplifiable. In particular, if $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}[x]$ generate the same ideal, then they are associates.

So the property holds for $n$ a prime power, because then the polynomial ring is présimplifiable, which is a stronger condition. However, when trying to go from prime powers to arbitrary composites, we are not so lucky. For $n$ composite but not a prime power, the ideal $(n)$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ is not primary, so the ideal $(0)$ of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not primary, hence $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is not présimplifiable. For instance, $2=2(4)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}[X]$, but we have neither $2=0$ nor $4$ a unit. But nonetheless I believe the result holds.

To try to get the result for arbitrary $n$, the Chinese Remainder Theorem suggests itself instead. Factor $n$ as a product of prime powers, $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$. Suppose that $(a)=(b)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Moding out by the ideal $(p_i^{a_i})$, we get $(\overline{a})=(\overline{b})$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p_i^{a_i}\mathbb{Z}[X]$, so by the result for prime powers we know that there is a unit $\overline{u}_i$ of $\mathbb{Z}/p_i^{a_i}\mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that $\overline{a}\overline{u}_i=\overline{b}$. Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem we obtain a unit $u\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that $u\equiv u_i \pmod{(p_i^{a_i})}$ for each $i$, hence $au=b$ (to see it is a unit, just lift the inverses to get an inverse for $u$; to see that we have equality $au=b$, note that the Chinese Remainder Theorem guarantees it holds modulo the gcd of the ideals, but $(p_1^{a_1})\cdots(p_r^{a_r}) = (0)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}[X]$, so we actually have equality).

So it would seem, if I did not make some mistake, that for these rings you do have that $(a)=(b)$ if and only if $b=au$ for some unit $u$.

---

I think we can avoid using the sledgehammer theorem quoted above to show that if $p$ is a prime, then $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is présimplifiable.

Suppose that $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}/p^s\mathbb{Z}[X]$ are such that $ab=a$ and $a\neq 0$. We have $a(b-1)=0$; lift them to $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and write:
\begin{align*}
a &= a_0 + a_1x + \cdots +a_mx^m\\\
b-1 &= b_0 + b_1x + \cdots b_mx^m.
\end{align*}
I claim that $p|b_i$ for each $i$. Indeed, since the content of $a(b-1)$ is a multiple of $p^n$, but the content of $a$ is not a multiple of $p^n$, then the content of $b-1$ must be a multiple of $p$ (since the content of the product is the product of the contents).

Therefore, the content of $(b-1)^{n}$ is divisible by $p^n$, hence projecting down to $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}[X]$ we have that $(b-1)^n = 0$. Therefore,
$$b\left(b^{n-1} - \binom{n}{1}b^{n-2} + \cdots + (-1)^{n-1}\binom{n}{n-1}\right) = (-1)^{n}$$
hence $b$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Thus, if $ab=a$, then either $a=0$ or $b$ is a unit, and we conclude that $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is présimplifiable.

Comment: Thanks Arturo. This all looks correct to me, modulo the cited Theorem. I do wonder whether there is some really simple and direct proof that the rings  $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are presimplifiable. I find that I don't know any simple way of recognizing a unit in these rings, which is maybe what makes the problem tricky.

Comment: @SJR: It may indeed be possible to do it for those rings, rather than use the sledgehammer of that Theorem. Indeed, it seems reasonable to do something like this: if $ab=a$, then $a(b-1)=0$. If $a\neq 0$, then not all coefficients are divisible by $p^n$; look at the smallest which is not, and show that every coefficient of $b-1$ must be divisible by $p$ (using an argument similar to that used in Gauss's Lemma); then some power of $b-1$ is $0$, and expanding $(b-1)^n=0$ we get that $b$ is a unit. That should work.

Comment: Yes! In fact this IS the Gauss Lemma: If $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $p^{n}$ is a divisor of $a(b-1)$ but not of $a$, then by multiplicativity of content $p$ divides $b-1$.

Incidentally, the argument of your last paragraph can be streamlined a wee bit by observing  that if $A$ and $B$ are rings, then $(A\times B)[x]\simeq A[x]\times B[x]$. This all has the makings of a great guided exercise!

Comment: @SJR: Ha! I just finished writing out the Gauss's Lemma argument to show the ring of polynomials modulo $p^n$ is pr&eacute;simplifiable. (-: So there it is; guided by the paper suggested by Robin Chapman and Bill Dubuque, but reasonably elementary and self-contained.