# a and b associates implies that $\exists u\in A$ unit such that $a=bu$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know that in a domain $A$, $a,b\in A$ are associates if and only if there exists a unit $u\in A$ such that $a=bu$. But, when A is not a domain, but a general unitary and commutative ring, we can only prove the second implication.

However, I haven't been able to find a counterexample ( a pair a,b in a unitary and commutative ring such that a and b are associates but there is no unit u such that $a=bu$). Of course, as I was told the biconditional was only true in domains, I tried looking at rings $\mathbb{Z}_n$ with n no prime. But, the double implication seems to hold for all of them.

My question are:

1)Is it true the double implication in every $\mathbb{Z}_n$? Does it hold for any principal ideal ring? If the answer is yes, how can I prove it?

2)Can you give a counterexample for the double implication?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589411/associated-elements-in-a-ring) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/if-r-is-a-commutative-ring-with-identity-and-a-b-in-r-are-divisible-by-eac?rq=1). For $\mathbb{Z}_n$, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901617/in-mathbbz-n-does-a-b-imply-that-a-and-b-are-associates?rq=1).

Comment: Okay, I see there are counterexamples but they are not trivial. About $\mathbb{Z}_n$, I don't see that last topic solve my question

Comment: I got it thank you