# Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit. Show that $\langle a\rangle = \langle b\rangle \iff a$ and $b$ are friends

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit. $\langle a\rangle = \langle b\rangle \iff a$ and $b$ are friends.

So the direction of $a,b$ friends $\implies$ is trivial.

I can't manage to prove the other direction though. Can anyone help me?

I started with that: The ideals are equal so $a\in \langle b\rangle$ so there exists $c\in R$ such that $a=bc$. The same goes for exists $d\in R$ such that $b=ad$ so we get $a(1-dc)=0$ so I need to prove $1-dc$ isn't a zero divisor but got no idea how.

Comment: What does "friends" mean?

Comment: Friends means there exists $u\in R^{\times}$ such that $a=bu$

Comment: The usual terminology is *associates* instead of *friends*.

Comment: Oh really? In Hebrew it's called "haverim" which translates to "friends" xD

Answer (score 2):

> I can't manage to prove the other direction though.

It's not your fault, it is not possible to prove [because there are counterexamples](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/589411/29335). (See also the linked questions to that question.)

The only reasonable context in which the converse you suggest is true is when $R$ is a domain, that is, cancellation is possible.

Comment: Thanks you very much! I thought that might be the problem but you know... I usually think the TA knows everything better xD