# example of commutative ring where two equal principal ideals have generators which do not differ by a unit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Can it be the case that for some $a,b \in R$, $(a) = (b)$ but $a \ne bu$ for all units $u \in R$?

Motivation: In an algebra lecture the presenter remarked that if $R$ is an integral domain, $(a) = (b)$ implies $a = bu$ for some unit $u$. This is elementary to show: since $a \in (b)$ and $b \in (a)$ we have $a = bc$ and $b = da$, hence $a = adc$. In an integral domain this implies $cd = 1$, and so by definition $c$ and $d$ are units.)

I then started trying to find an example of a ring where this doesn’t hold. I tried to find such an example in $\mathbb{Z}/n$, but had difficulty... three hours later I proved that this property always holds in $\mathbb{Z}/n$, despite that $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is not in general an integral domain. (I showed $(a) = (b)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n$ iff $\gcd(a,n) = \gcd(b,n)$, then showed the units of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n$ act transitively on the set of such elements, then used the Chinese remainder theorem.)

I haven’t been able to think of a counterexample, or a proof which doesn’t require $R$ to be an integral domain. A hint would be much appreciated (I’d rather not have a spoiler).

Comment: Answer at the duplicate: "For a "universal" counterexample outside $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$, take $R = k[x,y]/(yx^2-y)$, where $k$ is any field: here $(y) = (xy)$, but $y$ and $xy$ are not associates."

Comment: Another post here is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589411/associated-elements-in-a-ring/589569#589569).

Comment: Thanks! Lol, just as someone previously incorrectly gave $\mathbb{Z}/6$ as a counterexample, so too did the author of the book.) This would make a great take home exam problem.