# Can something divide one of its divisors?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $x$ be an element of a ring and $d$ a divisor of $x$. Can we have $x \mid d$?

There's the trivial case where both $x$ and $d$ are units. Otherwise, we have $x=da$ and $d=xb$, thus $x=xba$, so the question reduces to: can an element divide itself?

Comment: So the trivial case is when $x$ and $d$ are associates, i.e. they differ by a unit: $x=da$ where $a$ is unit. Furthermore, if the ring is an integral domain, then this is a necessary condition. As you say, if $x=da$ and $d=xb$ gives $x=xba$ and in the case of integral domains, we get $1=ba$ and so $a$ is a unit.

Comment: Take a look at this [thread.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/if-r-is-a-commutative-ring-with-identity-and-a-b-are-its-elements-that-are)

Comment: @Prism So in the integral domain case, we could continue $x(1 - ba) = 0\implies ba=1$, and so either $b$ or $a$ is a unit?

Comment: Actually, in an integral domain, the condition $ba=1$ implies that _both_ $b$ and $a$ are units.

Comment: @prism think about composing an answer!

Comment: @rschwieb: I tried… :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been previously considered in this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/are-associates-unit-multiples-in-a-commutative-ring-with-1). Here's a recap:

Robin Chapman gives a reference to the freely-available paper *[When are Associates Unit Multiples?](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-34/issue-3/When-are-Associates-Unit-Multiples/10.1216/rmjm/1181069828.full)* by Anderson, Axtell, Forman and Stickles.

In the paper, the following notation is used: Let $R$ be a commutative ring. If two elements $a, b \in R$ satisfy $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$, then they are called *associates* and we write $a\sim b$. If two elements $a, b\in R$ satisfy $a=u b$ for some unit $u$, then they are called *strongly associates* and we write $a\approx b$.

OP's question seems to be: Which elements $a, b\in R$ in the ring satisfy $a\sim b$?

It is clear that if $a\approx b$, then $a\sim b$ (see comments above). The paper above by Anderson et al. aims to describe (among other things) the commutative rings $R$ in which $a\sim b$ implies $a\approx b$ for all $a, b \in R$. If $R$ is an integral domain, then this is clearly true. (See Timothy Wagner's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14305/49227)).

Here is a more general theorem due to Kaplansky:

> If $R$ is principal ideal ring, or Artinian ring, or a ring satisfying
> $Z(R )\subset J(R )$ (here $Z(R )$ is the centre of $R$, and $J(R )$
> is Jacobson radical of $R$), then $a\sim b$ implies $a\approx b$ for
> all $a, b \in R$.

Comment: I never expected the answer to be this complicated! In any case, the situations that interest me are all integral domains.

Comment: @JackM: Me neither… :)