# Associates in the ring of continuous real-valued functions on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, proof-verification

I have tried to give a proof of the following theorem but I feel very unsure and would be very grateful if someone would check it for me

Many thanks!

> *Theorem.* Let $R$ be the ring $C[0,1]$ of continuous real-valued functions on the interval $[0, 1]$ (with pointwise operations). If $f, g \in R\setminus\{0\}$ satisfy $f \,|\, g$ and $g \,|\, f$, then there is some unit $u \in R$ such that $f = ug$.

*Proof.* First observe that the units in $C[0,1]$ are precisely the functions which are nowhere zero.

Since $g\,|\,f$ (say $f=sg$) and $f\,|\,g$ (say $g=tf$) we have

1) $f(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow g(x)=0$;

2) $s(x)=0 \Rightarrow f(x)=0$;

3) $t(x)=0 \Rightarrow g(x)=0$;

Thus we reduce to the case where $f$ and $g$ are both non-units.

There is some $(a,b)\subseteq[0,1]$ such that

1) $f$ and $g$ are both non-zero on $(a,b)$;

2) either $f(a)=g(a)=0$ or $f(b)=g(b)=0$ (wlog we assume the former).

We see that $s(x)=\dfrac{1}{t(x)}$ for all $x \in (a,b)$ and so, since $t$ is bounded, we cannot have $s(a)=0$.

It follows that $s$ is a unit. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this piecewise linear function as $f(x)$:

[image: Look at this function]

Now let $u(x)$ be the following piecewise linear function:
[image]

Let's look at your proof with $f(x)=g(x)$.  We can use  the functions $s(x)=u(x)$ and $t(x)=1$ because $f(x)=u(x)f(x)$ and $f(x)=1*f(x)$.

The problem is that you can't just use any $s(x)$ and $t(x)$, you need to construct them.
[Since you are only asking for a check of the proof, I won't propose a solution.]

Comment: Why does my interval not exist? Surely it's just (something like - I can't read the axes precisely) $(0.675,1)$? Thank you for your help so far :)

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I misread your interval.  But I still think theres a problem with the proof. Because we can make $u$ and $v$ so that $f=uf$ And $f=vf$ but neither of $u$ nor $v$ are units.

Comment: Yes, I see the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not true as it is shown by a simple example of Kaplansky which can be found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14274/121097).