# Ring and generator ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring and $r,s∈R$

So this is true

If $r=st$ for some $t∈R^x$, then $(r)=(s).$

$R^x$ being the units in $R$

Why is it true and why is the converse not?

If $(r)=(s)$, then $r=st$ for some $t∈R^x$

My thought process for part 1 is $r = st$ then $r ∈ (s)$ by the definition of an ideal. Then we can just generate the rest of $(r)$ so $(r) ⊆ (s)$. Also if t is a unit the $rt^{-1} = s$ and by the same logic $(s) ⊆ (r)$

Comment: Your argument about the first part is correct. I'll see if I can come up with a simple counter-example to the second part.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain it a bit I'm confused about gc in the poster's example does not imply 1 I thought a unit by definition has the multiplicative inverse property? Obviously, this doesn't work if the ring doesn't have units but would this not work for every ring with units?

Comment: @BingBong Not sure what you are talking about. The post at least links to duplicates that give examples of rings in which $(r)=(s)$ but $r\neq st$ for any unit $t$.  For example this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3019359/29335 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14270/29335