# Divisibility in Integers and General Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If x|y and y|x in integers, does this imply x=y?

Similarly, for any general ring, if x|y and y|x in the ring, does this imply x=y?

Comment: Did you try $x=1,y=-1$?

Comment: Consider $2$ and $-2$. If $x \mid y$ and $y \mid x$, $x$ and $y$ are called associates.

Comment: Furthermore, it is equivalent to $a=ub$ for some invertible $u$ in the ring. In the case of the integers, the only invertible elements are $\pm 1$, so $a|b\iff a=\pm b$.

Comment: @YuvalGat Not generally true. It is true in domains that elements are associate iff they are unit multiples of each other, but that is not true in general rings, [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14310/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque Of course, thank you for the correction!