# GCDs in integral domains are unique up to unit factors (associates)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The book I am reading mentioned that the greatest common divisor of $a_1, \cdots a_n$ in an integral domain $R$, whenever it exists, is unique up to arbitrary invertible factors. What does "up to arbitrary invertible factors" mean?

Definition: Let $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ be nonzero elements of the ring $R$. An element $d \in R$ is a greates comon divisor of $a_1, \cdots a_n$ if it possesses the properties:

- $d \vert a_i$, for $i=1, c\dots n$
- $c \vert a_i$, for $i=1, \cdots n$ implies $c \vert d$.

Comment: The definition of $\gcd$ varies from a text to another, what is yours?

Comment: I just added the definition.

Comment: Note that the definition can be restated as $\,c\mid d\!\!\!\overset{\rm\ \  def}\iff\! c\mid a_1,\ldots ,a_n,\,$ which make this (and other) proofs very simple - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [universal $\rm\color{#c00}{def}$inition of the gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198801/242), If $\,d,d'$ are both gcds of all of the $\,a_i\,$ then $\,c\mid d\!\!\!\overset{\rm\ \  \color{#c00}{def}}\iff\! c\mid a_1,\ldots ,a_n\!\!\!\overset{\rm\ \ \color{#c00}{def}}\iff\! c\mid d',\,$ so for $\,c=d\,$ we get $\,d\mid d'$ and for $\,c = d'\,$ we get $\,d'\mid d,\,$ so $\,d,d'$ divide each other so are associate ([thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14270/242) $\,d' = u d\,$ for some unit $u,\,$ being in a domain).

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. It does not seem trivial(the link), though the book treated it like it was. thanks!

Comment: The second answer, by Timothy Wagner, from the link mentioned that $s$ and $r$ are implied to be units. How so?

Comment: @TheLastCipher In a domain: $\,\large d\mid d'\!\mid d\,\Rightarrow\, d\overset{\Large *\,r}\longrightarrow d'\overset{\Large *\,s}\longrightarrow d\, $ so $\,\large \,rs\, d = d\,$ so $\,\large \,rs = 1\,$ by cancelling $\large \,d\neq 0\ \ $

Comment: I have arrive at that same computation independently. What I am asking is how does $rs = 1$ imply $r=1=s$?

Comment: $r$ and $s$ are units does mean $r=1=s$, right?

Comment: @TheLastCipher No, *a unit* is an invertible element (vs. *the unit* $1)$. We are showing, that the gcds are unique *up to  being associates, i.e. up to a unit factor* (the unit $\,r\,$ or $\,s\,$ above).

Comment: gcds are unique up to being associates mean that a gcd is a 'multiple' of another gcd?

Comment: @TheLastCipher By definition, in a domain, $a$ and $b$ are associate if they divide each other, i.e. $\, a\mid b\mid a.\,$ As we saw above, in a domain this is equivalent to $\, a = ub\,$ for some unit (invertible) $u,\,$ so $\,b = u^{-1} a,\,$ i.e. they are both unit multiples of each other.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks for claifying the definition. I unwittingly misunderstood the definition of unit.

Comment: @TheLastCipher For motivation see also [posts on *unit normalization* of gcds](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+unit+normalization).

Comment: The link seems broken.

Comment: @TheLastCipher Oops, should be [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+unit+normalization)   (had to change "me" to my userid = 242).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$$\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}$It means

> if $d$ is a GCD, then for each unit $\epsilon$ we have that $\epsilon d$ is a GCD, and all GCDs have this form.

For instance in $\Z$ the pair $2, 3$ has the two GCDs $1, -1$.

---

I am taking the following definition. Let $R$ be an integral domain, and $a_{1}, \dots, a_{n} \in R$. An element $d \in R$ is said to be a GCD of $a_{1}, \dots, a_{n}$ if

1. $d \mid a_{i}$ for all $i$;
2. for each $e \in R$, if $e \mid a_{i}$ for all $i$, then $e \mid d$.

Of course a GCD need not exist for all choices of $a_{1}, \dots , a_{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $d$ is a common divisor of $a,b$ and $e$ is a unit, then $ed$ is a common divisor of $a,b$, since if $a=a'd$ and $b=b'd$ for some $a',b'$, then $a=(a'e^{-1})(ed)$ and $b = (b'e^{-1})(ed)$. This indeed means that the gcd is unique up to invertible elements.