# Associates of a commutative ring with identity

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose *R* is a commutative ring with identity, how do the elements of *R* relate to associates?

I know that for $\mathbb{Z}$, the units are $\pm$1 and thus the associates of any element *n* of $\mathbb{Z}$ are $\pm$*n* but I'm curious if every element is an associate of itself for any commutative rings with identity. Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which definition of "associate" are you using?  In general commutative rings it can mean $\,a\sim b\iff a\mid b\mid a,\,$ i.e. $(a) = (b)$ or it can mean $a = u b$ for some unit $u$. They are equivalent in domains but  [*not* in commutative rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/are-associates-unit-multiples-in-a-commutative-ring-with-1) It doesn't matter for your 2nd question but may for your first (depending on what it means - which is not clear).

Comment: *Suppose R is a commutative ring with identity, how do the elements of R relate to associates?* That is kind of an ironic muddling to which I would say **'Being  associates' is a relationship between elements.**  It sounds a bit like you're thinking of "associates" as almost being the same thing (or a special subset) of "elements" in the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited in response to comments:

To answer your question, you need to define "associate".

I will say elements $a$ and $b$ of a ring are associates if $a=ub$ for some unit $u$.

The multiplicative identity element (call it $1$) of a ring is always a unit, and $a=1a$,

so I would say that every element in a commutative ring with identity is an associate of itself.

This concurs with the reflexive property of associatedness as an equivalence relation.

The additive inverse of $1$ (denoted $-1$) is also always a unit,

so every element in a commutative ring with identity is also an associate of its additive inverse.

Some rings have additional units; for example, the Gaussian integers $\mathbb Z[i]$ also have $i$ and $-i$ as units.

Comment: Elements $a$ and $b$ of a ring are said to be associates if $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$.

Comment: This is equivalent to $a=ub$ for some unit $u$ when the ring is an integral domain, but not in general.

Comment: @user26857:  I edited to qualify my answer accordingly